# How to remove variable from session array according to id PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

im trying to remove a product from my shopping cart after adding them.

can you please help

this is my code

ADD TO CART

html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']?>
<input type="double" name="weight" placeholder="Weight?" required>
```

PHP:

```
session_start();

$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$weight = $_POST['weight'];

$p = "pid";
$p .= (string) $pid;
$w = "weight";
$w .= (string) $pid;

$_SESSION[$p]=$pid;
$_SESSION[$w] = $weight;

if(isset($_SESSION)){
  header('location:../shopping-cart.php');
}
```

after execution the product is added.

Display in Cart

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $values){
    if(strpos($key, "pid") !== false){
        $sql="select * from products where product_id = $_SESSION[$key]";
        $result=$connect->query($sql);
        $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $w = "weight";
        $w .= (string) $r['product_id'];
        $weight = $_SESSION[$w];
```

HTML PHP CODE

```
<?php echo $r["product_name"];?>    
<?php echo 'LBP '.number_format($r['product_price'],0)?>
<input type="hidden" id="unitprice" onchange="f();" value="<?php echo $r['product_price']?>">
<input type="text" onchange="f();" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $weight ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Delete">
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $r['product_id'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="pweight" value="<?php echo $weight ?>">
```

remove from cart is not working
Any Help?

```
session_start();


    $pidremove = $_POST['pid'];
    $weightremove = $_POST['pweight'];


foreach($_SESSION as $key => $values){
   if($_SESSION[$w]==$pidremove)
   {
       unset($_SESSION[$w]);
       unset($_SESSION[$p]);
       echo 'done';
   }

}
```

Comment: _Small Note_ Everything that comes through $_POST is already a string so the cast in `$p .= (string) $pid;` is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove">
```

PHP:

```
unset($_SESSION['pid' . $_POST['pid']]
unset($_SESSION['weight' . $_POST['pid']]
```

Comment: This was useful. Thanks!